# Odoo: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, postgresql-9.1, odoo-10

Trying to re-install Odoo
Did the following steps:

1. Deleted the previous odoo dir
2. Deleted previous postgres users and databases, except the user which I was using and that user created databases
3. Tried the regular user and database creation in postgres

But once I try to install a module.

I am getting the following error.

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'MY OLDER DIRECTORY'
```

How can I change the path for my new directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the Odoo configuration file. This file contains directory name where Odoo looks up for the modules. In this case, your Odoo settings are left behind after deletion of the Odoo. Delete or modify this file accordingly to your new Odoo installation.

Where to look: for different platforms (Linux-Windows) or different OS's (CentOs, Ubuntu) it might be different directories

Comment: I guess it is showing me the previous addons path, which I mentioned before.

Comment: Right. Addons paths are written in the configuration file